History of quantum mechanics - Resource request
I am someone with a background in physics and was wondering what text is a good starting point for understanding the history of quantum mechanics.

Pais, A. (1986) Inward Bound: Of Matter and Forces in the Physical World. Oxford University Press and Baggott, J. E. (2011). The quantum story: a history in 40 moments. Oxford University Press.

On the early history of QM, Kuhn, Black-Body Theory and the Quantum Discontinuity, 1894–1912. On the later history, Kragh, Quantum Generations: a History of Physics in the Twentieth Century. Both are classics. On history of QFT, if it is included, Cao, Conceptual Developments of 20th Century Field Theories.

Thank you very much @ GeorgEssl and @ Conifold, will definitely chem these these out!

There are several good books on the history of QM. First of all,
Van der Waerden, Sources of Quantum mechanics, which contains an English translation of the main papers, with commentaries. Then:
Sin-Itiro Tomonaga, Quantum mechanics, vol. I Old quantum mechanics, and vol. II New quantum theory,
and also by the same author: The story of spin. These are the best on my taste. Another comprehensive history is
Mituo Taketani et al. Formation and logic of quantum mechanics, in 3 volumes: The formation of atomic models, The way to quantum mechanics, and The establishment and logic of quantum mechanics.
There are comprehensive treatises. On the lighter side:
Jim Baggott, The quantum story. The history in 40 moments.
Finally, some quantum mechanics books have first chapters dedicated to history (with more or less detail). One of my favorites is:
Steven Weinberg, Lectures on quantum mechanics. Chap. I Historical introduction (27pp).
Added. Found a Youtube video on the subject today.

Linus Pauling, along with E Bright Wilson published a definitive (495 page) text on QM in 1935 and then again in 1963. Might be free on the internet archive. Pauling and Wilson were on scene during the golden years for QM.
